# How do you render primitives as wireframes in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

How do you render primitives as wireframes in OpenGL?

Comment: Be more specific on the OpenGL version you are using.

Comment: With [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) you can simpli use the [wireframe](http://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Context.html#ModernGL.Context.wireframe) attribute of the [Context](http://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Context.html#ModernGL.Context) class

Comment: use GL_LINES to draw wireframes

Comment: This will help for most reader as it explains how to implement it
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

Answer (score 416):

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
```

to switch on,

```
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
```

to go back to normal.

Note that things like texture-mapping and lighting will still be applied to the wireframe lines if they're enabled, which can look weird.

Answer (score 49):

From [http://cone3d.gamedev.net/cgi-bin/index.pl?page=tutorials/ogladv/tut5](https://web.archive.org/web/20090119194513/http://cone3d.gamedev.net/cgi-bin/index.pl?page=tutorials/ogladv/tut5)

```
// Turn on wireframe mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);

// Draw the box
DrawBox();

// Turn off wireframe mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

Comment: making two calls is redundant. use GL_FRONT_AND_BACK

Comment: As an addendum to @shoosh's comment, the Red Book states that GL_FRONT and GL_BACK have been deprecated and removed from OpenGL 3.1 and up.  Now, you can still use them through the compatibility extension, but if you have a choice between forward-compatible and backward-compatible, I would recommend going for the former.

Answer (score 30):

Assuming a forward-compatible context in OpenGL 3 and up, you can either use `glPolygonMode` as mentioned before, but note that lines with thickness more than 1px are now deprecated. So while you can draw triangles as wire-frame, they need to be very thin. In OpenGL ES, you can use `GL_LINES` with the same limitation.

In OpenGL it is possible to use geometry shaders to take incoming triangles, disassemble them and send them for rasterization as quads (pairs of triangles really) emulating thick lines. Pretty simple, really, except that geometry shaders are notorious for poor performance scaling.

What you can do instead, and what will also work in OpenGL ES is to employ *fragment* shader. Think of applying a texture of wire-frame triangle to the triangle. Except that no texture is needed, it can be generated procedurally. But enough talk, let's code. Fragment shader:

```c
in vec3 v_barycentric; // barycentric coordinate inside the triangle
uniform float f_thickness; // thickness of the rendered lines

void main()
{
    float f_closest_edge = min(v_barycentric.x,
        min(v_barycentric.y, v_barycentric.z)); // see to which edge this pixel is the closest
    float f_width = fwidth(f_closest_edge); // calculate derivative (divide f_thickness by this to have the line width constant in screen-space)
    float f_alpha = smoothstep(f_thickness, f_thickness + f_width, f_closest_edge); // calculate alpha
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(.0), f_alpha);
}
```

And vertex shader:

```c
in vec4 v_pos; // position of the vertices
in vec3 v_bc; // barycentric coordinate inside the triangle

out vec3 v_barycentric; // barycentric coordinate inside the triangle

uniform mat4 t_mvp; // modeview-projection matrix

void main()
{
    gl_Position = t_mvp * v_pos;
    v_barycentric = v_bc; // just pass it on
}
```

Here, the barycentric coordinates are simply `(1, 0, 0)`, `(0, 1, 0)` and `(0, 0, 1)` for the three triangle vertices (the order does not really matter, which makes packing into triangle strips potentially easier).

The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that it will eat some texture coordinates and you need to modify your vertex array. Could be solved with a very simple geometry shader but I'd still suspect it will be slower than just feeding the GPU with more data.

Comment: I thought this looked promising, however this doesn't appear to work in any capacity with OpenGL 3.2 (non-ES). Although it's possible I messed something up, I played around with this for quite a bit and am not really sure how this is even intended to be used.

Any more information on what you intend to actually render with these shaders would be helpful; I don't see how anything other than a fill would produce anything useful, but that doesn't even work given that the alpha value of gl_FragColor appeared to be entirely ignored in OpenGL 3.2...

Comment: Of course it does. You can refer to someone's implementation of the same idea in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361582/opengl-debugging-single-pass-wireframe-rendering.

Comment: Is it capable of producing lines thicker than 1px?

Comment: The problem I run into trying to use your suggested implementation is, I think, that the shader will never be drawing outside of the object to be outlined. This will therefore draw the outline over the object being outlined? In other words, the outline will be purely contained within the original object to be drawn?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Although you can still get around that by inflating the object in the vertex shader.

Comment: In that case though, if I were drawing the outline around a textured object, I'd have to adjust my textures accordingly? Otherwise I believe they would be stretched.

Comment: See "Drawing a border on a 2d polygon with a fragment shader" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035719/drawing-a-border-on-a-2d-polygon-with-a-fragment-shader/18068177#18068177

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to do that without binding the additional coordinates and without using a geometry shader ? (I've been doing that with a GS and it works fine, but now I'd like to do that on a webGL engine that does not support GS).

Comment: @BrunoLevy you can get additional coordinated in webGL, no? If you are lucky, you might be able to get those coordinates from texcoords if you have very simple models but otherwise you just need to add new coordinates. Would be too nice if it worked without it :). All you need is to pass a single scalar per vertex (and then expand it to a 3-vector in the vertex shader).

Comment: I'd like to do that without adding an attribute (because it will change the API of the engine I'm using) but it does not seem possible. The single-scalar expanded in the VS is the best idea I've heard so far, I'll do that.

Comment: There is an online example of this here: http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/

Comment: There's no glPolygonMode in ES.

Comment: @Victor rephrased the answer, I guess that sentence got a bit too convoluted.

Comment: I like this answer.  I've done the same thing before (not in OpengGL ... was debuggin mesh generation, in a software renderer).  The problem I had there was that my line thickness was in barycentric space.  I wanted a tiny triangle to be almost entirely EDGE and almost no INTERIOR, whilst a massive triangle was the opposite.  Is your line thickness in screen space?

Comment: Ah, now I see ... f_width() is my friend, in this respect.  Thanks

Comment: There is also an interesting whitepaper from Nvidia: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/direct3d/Source/SolidWireframe/Doc/SolidWireframe.pdf

Answer (score 9):

In Modern OpenGL(OpenGL 3.2 and higher), you could use a Geometry Shader for this:

```
#version 330

layout (triangles) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

in vec2 texcoords_pass[]; // texcoords from Vertex Shader
in vec3 normals_pass[]; // normals from Vertex Shader

out vec3 normals; // normals for Fragment Shader
out vec2 texcoords; // texcoords for Fragment Shader

void main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++)
    {
        texcoords=texcoords_pass[i]; // pass through
        normals=normals_pass[i]; // pass through
        gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position; // pass through
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

- For points, change `layout (line_strip, max_vertices=3) out;` to `layout (points, max_vertices=3) out;`
- [Read more about Geometry Shaders](https://open.gl/geometry)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the fixed pipeline (OpenGL < 3.3) or the compatibility profile you can use

```
//Turn on wireframe mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

//Draw the scene with polygons as lines (wireframe)
renderScene();

//Turn off wireframe mode
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
```

In this case you can change the line width by calling [glLineWidth](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLineWidth.xhtml)

Otherwise you need to change the polygon mode inside your draw method (glDrawElements, glDrawArrays, etc) and you may end up with some rough results because your vertex data is for triangles and you are outputting lines. For best results consider using a [Geometry shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) or creating new data for the wireframe.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to draw the primitives as `GL_LINE_STRIP`.

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
/* Draw vertices here */
glEnd();
```

Comment: not if it is a bunch of GL_TRIANGLES: you would get lines between them.
In OpenGL 1.x or legacy you use glPolygonMode. 
In recent OpenGL you play with the geometry shader.

Comment: This is an ancient way of doing things that needs to be left behind.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
void glPolygonMode(GLenum face, GLenum mode);
```

`face`: Specifies the polygon faces that mode applies to. Can be `GL_FRONT` for the front side of the polygon, `GL_BACK` for the back and `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` for both.

`mode`: Three modes are defined.

- `GL_POINT`: Polygon vertices that are marked as the start of a boundary edge are drawn as points.
- `GL_LINE`: Boundary edges of the polygon are drawn as line segments. (your target)
- `GL_FILL`: The interior of the polygon is filled.

P.S: `glPolygonMode` controls the interpretation of polygons for rasterization in the graphics pipeline.

For more information look at the [OpenGL reference pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) in khronos group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use glut libraries like this:

1. for a sphere:

   ```
   glutWireSphere(radius,20,20);
   ```
2. for a Cylinder:

   ```
   GLUquadric *quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
   gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadratic,GLU_LINE);
   gluCylinder(quadratic,1,1,1,12,1);
   ```
3. for a Cube:

   ```
   glutWireCube(1.5);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If it's **OpenGL ES 2.0** you're dealing with, you can choose one of draw mode constants from

`GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP,  GL_LINES,` to draw lines,

`GL_POINTS` (if you need to draw only vertices), or

`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, and `GL_TRIANGLES` to draw filled triangles

as first argument to your

```
glDrawElements(GLenum mode, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const GLvoid * indices)
```

or

`glDrawArrays(GLenum mode, GLint first, GLsizei count)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

A good and simple way of drawing anti-aliased lines on a non anti-aliased render target is to draw rectangles of 4 pixel width with an 1x4 texture, with alpha channel  values of {0.,1.,1.,0.}, and use linear filtering with mip-mapping off. This will make the lines 2 pixels thick, but you can change the texture for different thicknesses.
This is faster and easier than barymetric calculations.